# Numeric Dropdownlistfor with loop in razor MVC 4

Tags: razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I have created this hardcoded dropdownlistfor in razor MVC, but I want to created this with a loop as it just contains integer values:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Bedrooms, new SelectList(new[] { new { ID = 1, Name = "1" }, new { ID = 2, Name = "2" }, new { ID = 3, Name = "3" }, new { ID = 4, Name = "4" }, new { ID = 5, Name = "5" }, new { ID = 6, Name = "6" }, new { ID = 7, Name = "7" } }, "ID", "Name"), "-Bedrooms-")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to add an extra property to your model.
And fill the List in your constructor or you can put it directly into the get of the extra property and remove the set. To make it easier I just put it in the constructor.

ViewModel

```
public class ViewModelName
{
   ...

   public ViewModelName()
   {
       PossibleAmountOfBedRooms = new List<SelectListItem>();

       for(int i; i < 8; i++)
         PossibleAmountOfBedRooms.Add(new SelectListItem{Text=i.ToString(), Value=i.ToString()});
   }

   public List<SelectListItem> PossibleAmountOfBedRooms {get; set;}

   ...
}
```

Then in your View you can do the following

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Bedrooms, Model.PossibleAmountOfBedRooms , "-Bedrooms-")
```

---

There is also another way but I don't prefer this way of working.
This way you would build the select in your view without using a helper method (Not strongly typed). If you ever change your ViewModel this piece if code could fail without you noticing.

In your View:

```
...
<select Id="Bedrooms" name="Bedrooms">
  <option value="">-Bedrooms-</option>
  @for(int i; i < 8; i++)
  {
      <option value="@i">@i</option>
  }
</select>
...
```